# How to handle and update count sharing via Pinterest by javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, pinterest

I use Pinterest API and a custom button for my website and implement sharing any image in current page.

It works well. And show counter share in the first time we link page.

But **I dont know how to handle and update counter before we "Pin It" successfully via Pinterest**

Could you suggest me any solution for that.

My code

Javascript:

```
Widget.snsShare = function($) {
  var init = function(){
    init_pinterest();
  };

  var init_pinterest = function(){
    (function(d){
      var f = d.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT')[0], p = d.createElement('SCRIPT');
      p.type = 'text/javascript';
      p.async = true;
      p.src = '//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js';
      f.parentNode.insertBefore(p, f);
      getcount();
    }(document));
  };

  var getcount = function() {
    var pr = {};
    pr['url'] = location.href;
    var options = {
      full_path: 'http://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json',
      data: pr
    }
    // This function will call function get count from api :
// http://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json
    Util.fetch(options).always(function(result) {
      var obj = result.responseText;
      obj =  obj.replace('receiveCount','');
      obj = eval(obj);
      count = obj.count;
      if (count > 1000) {
        count = (count / 1000).toFixed(1);
        if (count > 1000) count = (count / 1000).toFixed(1) + "M";
        else count = count + "k";
      }
      if (count > 0) {
        console.log(count);
        $('.count_pinterest').html(count);
      }      
    })
  }
  return {
    init: init,
  };
}(jQuery);
```

The View

```
....
    li.share_list_item
    a data-pin-custom='true' data-pin-count='beside' data-pin-do="buttonBookmark" data-pin-round="true" href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?" style="margin-top: -5px;"
      =image_tag 'partials/pinterest', :height => "20px", :style => "cursor:pointer"
```

Comment: I don't think there is currently a good way to do that. Interesting and relevant idea though. I work for Pinterest, I'll see what I can do. :)

Comment: @ZackArgyle I see. No way to do that by js. Thanks. I'll research and use some plugin same as "addthis" ...
Thanks.